# C# wpf print content control without modifying size user interface

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, contentcontrol

I have a contentcontrol which I want to print, when printing the contentcontrol by default it gets on the middle of my A4.

So I changed the size of the contentcontrol to the size of A4 in order to print in following way:

```
printControl.Measure(new Size(816, 1056));
printControl.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(816, 1056)));
printControl.UpdateLayout();

PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{ 
    dialog.PrintVisual(printControl, sTitle); 
}
```

This achieves what I want and it looks correct on the A4 now when printed however in the user interface the size also gets altered and I try to get around that because it has negative effect.

The contentcontrol is in a grid on the second row. And after resizing it shifts over the first row containing a toolbar.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Grid.Row="0">
    //toolbar stuff here
    </ToolBar>
    <ContentControl Name="printControl" Grid.Row="1"></ContentControl>
 </Grid>
```

I have tried to resize it back to it's original size after printing but still stays shifted over the toolbar.

Also tried to define a second contentcontrol in code, copy the content and resize the second contentcontrol. But it seems it keeps reference to the original one because it still resizes in the user interface.

Does anyone have a pointer for me how to solve this?

**Update**

Managed to fix it in an easy way.
By calling arrange with only the size it positions the content control at 0,0. I needed to call Arrange also with the X and Y value to not shift over the toolbar.

In the end when print gets called I resize to A4 and print, when printing is finished I resize is back to the rendered size and position it below the toolbar and it works.

Comment: If your copy modifies the original then you did not create a copy, just another reference. How are you creating your copy?

Comment: ContentControl testControl = new ContentControl();
   testControl.Content = printControl.Content;

Comment: That creates a reference not a copy.  You need to create a new instance of printControl.Content and copy the values from the original, then assign the new instance to testControl.Content.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I managed to find an easier way to solve my problem, I've updated my post.